# let foo: Vec<Option<T>> = vec![None; 10]; without T implementing Clone

Tags: rust

I want to fill a Vector of "Option" with "None" values.
This is done with this code

```rust
let mut foo: Vec<Option<T>> = Vec::with_capacity(capacity);
for _ in 0..capacity {
    foo.push(None);
}
```

but actually I really would like to have this shorter like

```rust
let foo: Vec<Option<T>> = vec![None; capacity];
```

Unfortunately, my generic `T` is not clonable and therefore the expression cannot apply `None`. Is there a way to tell the expression that `None` is clonable?

Comment: You can `Vec::from_iter((0..capacity).map(|_| None))`

Comment: or `std::iter::repeat_with(|| None).take(capacity).collect::<Vec<_>>()`

Comment: I know you understand the why, but that question includes solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rust a trait can only be implemented for a type, not for individual variants of an enum, so unfortunately, `Option::<T>::None` may not be `Clone` if `T` is not.

Possible workarounds:

- Your original solution, albeit not a one-liner.
- `Vec::from_iter((0..capacity).map(|_| None))`, as suggested by [@cafce25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78146275/let-foo-vecoptiont-vecnone-10-without-t-implementing-clone#comment137769138_78146275).
- `std::iter::repeat_with(|| None).take(capacity).collect::<Vec<_>>()`, as suggested by [@vallentin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78146275/let-foo-vecoptiont-vecnone-10-without-t-implementing-clone#comment137769159_78146275).
- You can also use [`Vec::resize_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.resize_with), since `Option<T>` *will* be `Default`, no matter the `T`:

  ```rust
  let mut foo: Vec<Option<T>> = Vec::with_capacity(capacity);
  vec.resize_with(5, Default::default);
  ```
- You can declare a macro similar to `vec!` that will expand to one of the above, if you need to use such a declaration many times and want to de-noise the code a bit. However, it's probably best to not do this if you only need to create such a `Vec` a small number of times.